# Can I move the GNOME top bar (and status icons) to the side?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, top-bar, statusbar

I would like to have as much vertical screen space as possible, but I like having the status icons and time visible. Is there an extension to move the "top bar" to the left or right side, perhaps as part of a dock or side panel?

I'm aware of the *Hide Top Bar* extension as a fallback.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since [its October update](https://github.com/home-sweet-gnome/dash-to-panel/releases/tag/v24), the Dash to Panel GNOME Shell Extension supports vertical panel orientation.

**To install and enable the extension:**

1. Make sure that you have `chrome-gnome-shell` installed:

   ```
   sudo apt install chrome-gnome-shell
   ```
2. You also need the *GNOME Shell integration* browser extension installed. You can install it [for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/gnome-shell-integration/) or [for Chrome-based browsers](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gnome-shell-integration/gphhapmejobijbbhgpjhcjognlahblep?hl=en), depending on your choice of web browser.
3. Additionally, install Tweaks to access the extension's options (and a bunch of other useful GNOME settings):

   ```
   sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
   ```
4. Now, you can visit the [Dash to Panel GNOME Shell Extension webpage](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/), toggle the switch on the right-hand side of the page to *ON* and click *Install* on the pop-up.
5. Then, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, input `r` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to restart GNOME Shell and make the extension take effect.

**To enable the vertical panel:**

1. Open Tweaks
2. Go to *Extensions*.
3. Click the cog icon next to *Dash to Panel*.
4. Set *Panel screen position* to *Left* or *Right*.